# Vue Router Navigation Guards

Tags: vue.js, vuex, router

I have a page that can´t be accessed without permission. The permission is loaded by axios request in an action in the store. After the request the permission is stored in a store module. In the Navigation Guard beforeEach I have a getter that gets the permissions data from the store module.
Because it did not work I wrote a console.log to log the permissions data. The permissions data is an Array and when it logs the length of the Array it logs 0. That doesn´t make sense, because when I see into the Vue DevTools the store says that the array length is 1.

Does anyone have a solution that the store is faster?

Navigation Guard:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  var hasPermission = await store.getters.availableAppPermissions
  hasPermission.forEach(function(item) {
    if (
      to.path.includes(item.appUrl) &&
      to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresPermission)
    ) {
      next({ name: 'Home' })
    }
  })
  next()
})
```

Store Module:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  state: {
    availableApps: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_AVAILABLE_APPS(state, availableApps) {
      state.availableApps = availableApps
      state.permissions = true
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loadAppsAvailableForCurrentUser({ commit }) {
      return axios.get('/v1/apps').then(data => {
        // Filter out apps that have false set in show_in_menu
        const filteredApps = data.data.filter(app => app.showInMenu)

        commit('SET_AVAILABLE_APPS', filteredApps)
      })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    availableApps(state) {
      return state.availableApps
    },
    availableAppPermissions(state) {
      return state.availableApps.filter(item => item.hasPermission == false)
    }
  }
}
```

Code where loadAppsAvailableForCurrentUser is called:
This created is in the NavBar Component it is called on every Site because this Component is in the App.vue

```
created() {
  if (this.$store.getters.loggedIn) {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadUserData')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadUserImageBase64')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadVisibleTabs')
    this.$store.dispatch('loadAppsAvailableForCurrentUser')
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also post the code in which you call "loadAppsAvailableForCurrentUser"?

I would also point out that "state.permissions" is used within SET_VAILABLE_APPS, but not set in the state

Comment: @Zelig880 Added the code where the action is dispatched. Please ignore the state.permissions. I have tried something but it didn`t work

Comment: `await store.getters.availableAppPermissions` doesn't make sense because a value isn't a promise. If the router relies on values from loadAppsAvailableForCurrentUser, etc, it's a mistake to do this in a free manner in `created`, they should be done in a router. Also notice that initial router navigation happens before root component is mounted.